How to Customize Import Paths in a TypeScript npm Package?
Question:
I'm working on a TypeScript npm package and I'm trying to customize the import paths for convenience. After building my package, the structure looks like this:
File Structure:
- dist
  - utils
    - index.js
    - index.d.ts
  - index.js
  - index.d.ts

Code:
Before building, my index.ts file looks like this:
import { UtilityFunction } from './utils';
export { UtilityFunction };

Currently, I can import the module like this:
import { UtilityFunction } from '@mypackage/name';

However, I want to be able to import it using a more specific path, like this:
import { UtilityFunction } from '@mypackage/name/utils';

Here is my current tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist/types"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

My package.json includes the following:
{
  "name": "@mypackage/name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    "./utils": "./dist/utils/index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.3.2"
  }
}

Expected Outcome:
I want users to be able to import modules using:
import { UtilityFunction } from '@mypackage/name/utils';

Questions:

What changes are needed in my configuration to achieve the desired import paths?
How can I ensure that TypeScript can find the module and its type declarations without running into the aforementioned errors?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This question is similar to: How can I use paths in tsconfig.json?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: package.json `exports` field not working with TypeScript. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Be sure to read though the Package entry points section in the Node.js documentation — you'll need to use wildcard patterns (*) to remap specifiers to your dist directory.
